# Broadcast image to all Devices in which my app is installed (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two apps : 1. Admin app
                  2. User app

> I want to broadcast contents to user app which were added through admin app.
>   As far content is added, user app should have to get a notification that event is added.

But i'm new to android and don't know how to do that.
Can anyone tell me, what is keyword for i want or tell me the solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achive this using GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) you can find many tutorials if you search over google.
GCM allows us to send or broadcast a message over the network and the receivers in the client app (your apps) will receive and behave in the way you want it to

Comment: Thanks man. I Found this helpul. >> http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/